# wpf nested foreach index array out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, nested-loops

i created 2 foreach loop and i am getting error ( index outside of bounds of array ) , because i use 2 arrays .

This is what i do :

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\apr13mpsip\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\iStellarMobile\iStellarMobile\Puzzle\educational.txt"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) // read line by line.
    {
        column = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        rowcol = column;
    }

    int  i = 0;
    int  j = 0;

    foreach (string r in rowcol)
    {
        foreach (string c in column)
        {
            var currentValue = rowcol[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;                    
    }
}
```

i have already global string[] column; and string[] rowcol;

Error happens in this line :

> var currentValue = rowcol[i][j];

-------EDIT--------------------

This is how my textfile looks like :

[image]

From Tim's answer , rowcol[0][0] will print h and , rowcol[0][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jprn.jpg)] will print E , but the first [] of rowcol is null , whenever is more than 0 , it gives me an null error , Object not set to reference .

[image]

Comment: You're trying to access `rowcol` as a 2-dimensional array, when you've declared it as a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lines?  i.e., why are you using a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: because i got a txtfile which have 10 lines and 10 commas in each line, so i split the commas , i get 10 columns

Comment: Your code as is will only have the last line in the array (you're overwriting the array each time through the loop); it sounds like you're trying to create a table out of the file, yes?  Is the first line a header line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a jagged array, that way if you encounter a situation where you have more than 10 columns in a line it won't throw an out of bound error.

I'd also recommend using `File.ReadAllLines` as that will return an array of all the lines in the file.

Something like this (not tested) should get you going:

```
string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\apr13mpsip\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\iStellarMobile\iStellarMobile\Puzzle\educational.txt");

string[] lineValues;

int row = 0;
int col;

string[][] rowcol = new string[fileData.Length][];

foreach (string line in fileData)
{
    lineValues = line.Split(new string[]{ ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    rowcol[row] = new string[lineValues.Length];

    col = 0;

    foreach (string value in splits)
    {
        rowcol[row][col] = value;
        col++
    }

    row++;
}
```

What this code does is as follows:

```
1.  Populates the array `fileData` with the lines from the text file.
2.  Sets up an array to hold the split result on each line.
3.  Declares variables for row and col, and sets row to 0.
4.  Sets the first dimension of the jagged array `rowcol` to the length of the array of lines returned from `ReadAllLines` (i.e., the number of rows).
5.  Loop through each line in `fileData`, doing the following:
    a.  split the current line on ',' and put the results in `lineValues`.
    b.  Set the second array of `rowcol` for the current row equal to the length
        of the array `lineValues` (number of columns).
    c.  Set the `col` variable to 0 (first column).
    d.  Loop through each value in `lineValues`, assigning the current value to
        the proper column for the current row, and then increment the column counter.
6.  Once the inner loop is done, increment the row counter.
```

**Edit**
`rowcol` is a jagged array (an array of arrays), which basically means you have an array where each element is another array reference. Each of these array references can (but don't have to) have different lengths (in your case they don't).

```
string rowcol[][] = new string[fileData.Length][];
```

This initializes the jagged array rowcol to a length equal to the number of lines in your file (10). You now have 10 elements in the array, but they are all null.

```
rowcol[row] = new string[lineValues.Length];
```

This initializes the array reference for the current element (row) to equal the length (number) of values from the split.  Continuing with your example, you know have "x" elements (the number of values from the split) in the array at element "row", but they are null.

```
rowcol[row][col] = value;
```

You know have a value (string) that you can access.

So if you are in the inner loop, and you have code that will print the value of `rowcol[0][0]` and `rowcol[1][0]`, after the first time through the inner loop you'll have a value in `rowcol[0][0]`, but you won't in `rowcol[1][0]` because you haven't gotten to row 1 yet, you're still on row 0.

I tested this in a console app, and used the following snippet to print the values of the jagged array **after** the outer loop had finished:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowcol.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rowcol[i].GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row {0}, Col {1}: {2}", i, j, rowcol[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This results in the following output (whole output is not shown, just enough to give the general idea):

```
Row 0, Col 0: h
Row 0, Col 1: e
Row 0, Col 2: l
Row 0, Col 3: l
Row 0, Col 4: o
Row 0, Col 5:
Row 0, Col 6:
Row 0, Col 7:
Row 0, Col 8:
Row 0, Col 9:
Row 1, Col 0: o
Row 1, Col 1: 
Row 1, Col 2:
Row 1, Col 3:
Row 1, Col 4:
Row 1, Col 5:
Row 1, Col 6:
Row 1, Col 7:
Row 1, Col 8:
Row 1, Col 9:
Row 2, Col 0: l
Row 2, Col 1: i
Row 2, Col 2: v
Row 2, Col 3: e
Row 2, Col 4:
Row 2, Col 5:
Row 2, Col 6:
Row 2, Col 7:
Row 2, Col 8:
Row 2, Col 9:
....
Row 9, Col 0: 
Row 9, Col 1:
Row 9, Col 2:
Row 9, Col 3: d
Row 9, Col 4:
Row 9, Col 5:
Row 9, Col 6:
Row 9, Col 7:
Row 9, Col 8:
Row 9, Col 9:
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using that results in this error?  I just ran a quick test with the above code and it worked (except for a typo in the Split method, which I just fixed).

Comment: i replaced the spilt with lineValues . and i use the same as yours i only added to print rowcol[0][0] and print rowcol[1][0]; , [0][0] is fine , [1][0] gave me an null exception error

Comment: Where did you add the lines to print the rows? Has rowcol[1][0] been populated *before* you try to print it?

Comment: i added inside the inner foreach loop , i also tried the first layer of foreach . Regarding about the populated , how do i know if its being populated? Also another thing :  rowcol[row] = new string[lineValues.Length]; is assigning the size only? values are not assigned?